# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=null} to activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-camera, android-gallery, android-image-capture

This is my line code that I use to save pictures from camera and gallery on device:

Camera Intent:

```
   private void abrirCamera() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    image_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    //Camera intent
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA);
}
```

Gallery Intent:

```
    public void abrirGaleria() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
}
```

This is onActivityResult that is used to save folders on device:

```
 @NonNull
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onResume();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {//Verify the requestCode
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();

                try {

                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), contentURI);

                    int altura = bitmap.getHeight();//altura;
                    int largura = bitmap.getWidth();//largura

                    if (largura > 450) {

                        if (altura > largura) {//retrato

                            bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 600);
                            saveImage(bitmap);
                        }

                        if (largura > altura) {//paisagem

                            bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 600, 450);
                            saveImage(bitmap);
                        }

                        if (largura == altura) {//quadrado

                            bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 450);
                            saveImage(bitmap);
                        }

                    } else {
                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    salvarBD();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            atualizarLista();
        }

        if (requestCode == CAMERA && data == null) {//Android 10 (Android Q > API 23)
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver().query(image_uri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String caminho = cursor.getString(column_index);//diretorio
            cursor.close();

            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), image_uri);

                int altura = bitmap.getHeight();
                int largura = bitmap.getWidth();

                if (largura > 450) {

                    if (altura > largura) {//retrato

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 600);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura > altura) {//paisagem

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 600, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura == altura) {//quadrado

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    apagaFotoOriginal(caminho);

                }

                salvarBD();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            atualizarLista();
        }

        if (requestCode == CAMERA && String.valueOf(data).equals("Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }")) {

            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(image_uri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String caminho = cursor.getString(column_index);//diretorio
            cursor.close();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), image_uri);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);

                int altura = bitmap.getHeight();//altura;
                int largura = bitmap.getWidth();//largura

                if (largura > 450) {

                    if (altura > largura) {//retrato

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 600);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura > altura) {//paisagem

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 600, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura == altura) {//quadrado

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    apagaFotoOriginal(caminho);

                }

                salvarBD();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            atualizarLista();
        }

        if (requestCode == CAMERA && data == null) {//Android 10 (Android Q > API 23)
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver().query(image_uri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String caminho = cursor.getString(column_index);//diretorio
            cursor.close();

            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), image_uri);

                int altura = bitmap.getHeight();
                int largura = bitmap.getWidth();

                if (largura > 450) {

                    if (altura > largura) {//retrato

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 600);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura > altura) {//paisagem

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 600, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    if (largura == altura) {//quadrado

                        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 450, 450);
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                    }

                    apagaFotoOriginal(caminho);

                }

                salvarBD();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            atualizarLista();
        }

    }
}
```

Metod used to save pics on device, of accord with your Android Version:

```
   public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File diretorioAndroid8_9 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    if (!diretorioAndroid8_9.exists()) {//cria o diretorio caso não existir
        diretorioAndroid8_9.mkdirs();
    }

    try {

        id = foto_ugbDao.proximoID(compet, codugb);
        String teste = "";

        if (id <= 9) {// ID <= 9
            int a = id;
            String b = String.format("%02d", a);
            String fileName = compet + codugb + b;

            if (verificaNomeArquivo(fileName)) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {//Android 10 (Q)
                    salvarArquivoAPI29(myBitmap, bytes, fileName);
                } else {
                    salvarArquivoAPI23(bytes, diretorioAndroid8_9, b);
                }

            } else {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {//Android 10 (Q)
                    salvarArquivoAPI29(myBitmap, bytes, fileName);
                } else {
                    salvarArquivoAPI23(bytes, diretorioAndroid8_9, b);
                }

            }

        } else {// id >= 10
            String fileName = compet + codugb + id;

            if (verificaNomeArquivo(fileName)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {//Android 10 (Q)
                    salvarArquivoAPI29(myBitmap, bytes, fileName);

                } else {//criação de arquivo com id maior que 10, em API de nivel inferior a 29 (Android Q)
                    salvarArquivoAPI23(bytes, diretorioAndroid8_9, fileName);
                }
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {//Android 10 (Q)
                    salvarArquivoAPI29(myBitmap, bytes, fileName);
                } else {
                    salvarArquivoAPI23(bytes, diretorioAndroid8_9, fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

    private void salvarArquivoAPI23(ByteArrayOutputStream bytes, File diretorioAndroid8_9, String b) throws IOException {
    String ss = compet + codugb + id;
    File f = new File(diretorioAndroid8_9, ss);
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[]{f.getPath()},
            new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
    fo.close();
}

private void salvarArquivoAPI29(Bitmap myBitmap, ByteArrayOutputStream bytes, String fileName) throws IOException {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

    String diretorioAndroid10 = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + IMAGE_DIRECTORY;
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, diretorioAndroid10);
    Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

    if (uri != null) {
        outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "API29", String.valueOf(uri));
    } else {
        File f = new File(diretorioAndroid10, fileName + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
    }
}
```

And the log return:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=null} to activity {br.agr.terraviva.modelogestao/br.agr.terraviva.modelogestao.ui.act005.AuditoriaUGBActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5080)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5121)
> at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7604)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
> Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
> at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:515)
> at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
> at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:52)
> at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:141)
> at br.agr.terraviva.modelogestao.ui.act005.FA04.onActivityResult(FA04.java:350)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8136)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5073)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5121) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7604) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)